# Custom brush for sculpting?

Tags: mesh, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, sculpting, zbrush

Can I make a custom brush for sculpting with this materials and imitate some of the brushes from this paid pack?(paid pack: https://blendermarket.com/products/the-rock-essentials )

[image: https://www.poliigon.com/search/recent/narrow/list/cliff]

Comment: Brushes https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sRVu.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the displacement map of those textures as a brush.
I make and use textures for brushes in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxEmHaVlc4o

Comment: It would be useful to leave a summary of the information that is in the linked video, as links can change or go down. If the link goes down then future visitors will not have access to the information and this answer will not have much value.

Comment: That is true, however its not a simple answer and the video explaining it is 20 minutes long.

Comment: You can always leave links in comments section if you don't want to make proper answer.