# How to make photo scanned 3D brushes?

Tags: rendering, mesh, sculpting, zbrush

How to make photo scanned brushes if I have these?
[image]

Comment: You have asked essentially the same question twice already. Both [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82582/custom-brush-for-sculpting) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82631/how-to-create-custom-3d-brushes-using-displacement-maps).  Please edit your *original* post and add any information you feel may be necessary to make it more clear, answerable, or make any other improvements rather than duplicating posts. Thanks.

Comment: Please take a little tour on how to ask proper questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour If this isn't enough, check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help